# If $x_n\ge 0$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$ and $\sum_{n\in\Bbb N}x_n=0$ then $x_n=0$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$ necessarly.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, examples-counterexamples

Let be $(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ a not negative sequence of real number and we suppose that
$$
\sum_{n\in\Bbb N}x_n=0
$$
So if the last identity holds then it must be
$$
x_n=0
$$
for any $n\in\Bbb N$ necessarly? Indeed by standard analysis result I only know that the limit of a not negative sequence is not negative too. So could someone help me, please?

Comment: $x_n \ge 0$ implies that $x_n = u_n^2$ for some real sequence $(u_n)$, so this has been asked and answered before.

Comment: @MartinR I saw: but the answer of the linked question are much more complicated...

Comment: Then add a better answer to the old question. The purpose of closing questions as a duplicate is to have all solutions at one place.

Comment: @MartinR Before to write the question I searched into the site but unfortunately I did not find anything: even when I wrote the question the site did not suggest the linked question to me, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is not negative then
$$
0\le x_n\le\sum_{n\in\Bbb N}x_n=0
$$
for each $n\in\Bbb N$ so that
$$
x_n=0
$$
for each $n\in\Bbb N$.